# AndroidManifest.XML - </application> error

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I'm writing a super simple application in android-studio.
while trying to sync it, I get the following error message:

*The element type "application" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".*

However, there is a matching end-tag as you can see below.
I must missed something in here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="benda.leveling_v2"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Leveling"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="benda.leveling_v2.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="benda.leveling_v2.Laser"
            android:label="Laser readings"
            android:parentActivityName="benda.leveling_v2.MainActivity" />
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="benda.leveling_v2.About"
            android:label="About"
            android:parentActivityName="benda.leveling_v2.MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="benda.leveling_v2.LoadCells"
            android:label="Load cells"
            android:parentActivityName="benda.leveling_v2.MainActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

what do I miss?

Comment: `<activity>
    android:name="benda.leveling_v2.Laser"
    android:label="Laser readings"
                android:parentActivityName="benda.leveling_v2.MainActivity">
</activity>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
<activity
    android:name="benda.leveling_v2.Laser"
    android:label="Laser readings"
    android:parentActivityName="benda.leveling_v2.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

to

```
<activity
    android:name="benda.leveling_v2.Laser"
    android:label="Laser readings"
    android:parentActivityName="benda.leveling_v2.MainActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: Great. I was not familiar to the meaning of that "/" till now. thanks.